# How to restructure object from another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object structure that was made from my form that were dynamically created, so the field names were created based on index.

```
{
  "bookTitle_0": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
  "bookDescription_0": "Published in 1960, this timeless classic explores human behaviour and the collective conscience of The Deep South in the early 20th century. Humour entwines the delicate strands of prejudice, hatred, hypocrisy, love and innocence to create one of the best novels ever written.",
  "author_0": "Harper Lee",
  "borrowedBy_0_0": "John Doe",
  "borrowedBy_0_1": "John Doe Jr.",
  "bookTitle_1": "1984",
  "bookDescription_1": "Although 1984 has passed us by, George Orwell’s dystopian, totalitarian world of control, fear and lies has never been more relevant. Delve into the life of Winston Smith as he struggles with his developing human nature in a world where individuality, freewill and love are forbidden.",
  "author_1": "George Orwell",
  "borrowedBy_1_0": "John Doe III"
}
```

To process this easier or more effectively, i would like to transform the structure into something like:

```
[
  {
      "book": {
          "bookTitle": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
          "bookDesciption": "Published in 1960, this timeless classic explores human behaviour and the collective conscience of The Deep South in the early 20th century. Humour entwines the delicate strands of prejudice, hatred, hypocrisy, love and innocence to create one of the best novels ever written.",
          "author": "Harper Lee",
          "borrowedBy": {
               "name": "John Doe",
               "name": "John Doe Jr.",
           }
      },
      "book": {
          "bookTitle": "1984",
          "bookDesciption": "Although 1984 has passed us by, George Orwell’s dystopian, totalitarian world of control, fear and lies has never been more relevant. Delve into the life of Winston Smith as he struggles with his developing human nature in a world where individuality, freewill and love are forbidden.",
          "author": "George Orwell",
          "borrowedBy": {
               "name": "John Doe III"
           }
      }
  }
]
```

Any ideas how to do this? I'm not too familiar with javascript, but read somewhere I can try to use Array.reduce()? But I really have no idea how to create a structure like this.

Comment: the second object structure is problematic.  you have duplicated key "book" on an inner object.  I think that's supposed to be two object literals inside a single array right?

Comment: since the first structure is a (mega)object there is no gain in using Array functions. Looks like you'll need to parse the keys. If they are well-known then you'll likely be able to compose the keys using and index, kind of `myObject["bookTitle_"+i]`

Comment: This won't be possible `"borrowedBy": {"name": "John Doe","name": "John Doe Jr.",}`. The value will get overridden if we do like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the schema you are trying to achieve is:

```
var bookArr = [/*constains object of bookSchema*/]
var bookSchema = {
        "bookTitle": "",
        "bookDescription": "",
        "borrowedBy": {
            "name": ""
        }
    }
```

1. Bad way: You can convert your input to this by accessing each element of your input and filling a new object of `bookSchema` and push it to the array.
2. Good way: If the incoming input is in your hands please fix it (Again don't couple it up though but make a cleaner schema or use things like GraphQl).

Comment: Accepting this for #2, you're right, I should fix the data. It's much more complicated to fix it at this point than to fix it from where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

i can tell you two ways:

1- using Object.keys(originalObj):

```
    let keys = Object.keys(originalObj);
    let result = [];
    function assigner(key,newObj,value){
       if(!newObj) newObj = {};
       let endIdx = key.indexOf('_');
       let newKey = key.substring(0,endIdx);
       newObj[newKey] = value;
       return newObj;
    }
    let newObj =null;
    for(let i = 0;i<keys.length;i++)
    {
       if(keys[i].indexOf('bookTitle')>-1)
       {
          if(!newObj){
            result.push(Object.assign({},newObj));
            newObj = null;
          }
       }
     newObj = assigner(keys[i],newObj ,originalObj[keys[i]]);
    }
    console.log(result);
```

in above code i iterate throw your original object keys and create array of new objects

2- i also suggest not create your original object like that, instead create it like the one you expect to be, every time a value  be set in ui, you can create it in java script client side and keep it, and if your object come from server you can convert it to json and deserialize it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient way of solving the problem. But then this is one of the ways I could think of as a solution.

```js
let data = {
  "bookTitle_0": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
  "bookDescription_0": "Published in 1960, this timeless classic explores human behaviour and the collective conscience of The Deep South in the early 20th century. Humour entwines the delicate strands of prejudice, hatred, hypocrisy, love and innocence to create one of the best novels ever written.",
  "author_0": "Harper Lee",
  "borrowedBy_0_0": "John Doe",
  "borrowedBy_0_1": "John Doe Jr.",
  "bookTitle_1": "1984",
  "bookDescription_1": "Although 1984 has passed us by, George Orwell’s dystopian, totalitarian world of control, fear and lies has never been more relevant. Delve into the life of Winston Smith as he struggles with his developing human nature in a world where individuality, freewill and love are forbidden.",
  "author_1": "George Orwell",
  "borrowedBy_1_0": "John Doe III"
}

const requiredKeys = ["bookTitle", "bookDesciption", "author", "borrowedBy"]
const subKeys = {"borrowedBy": "name"}

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((result, obj, index) => {
  const keyArray = obj.split("_")
  const bookObj = result[keyArray[1]] || {}
  
  if(subKeys[keyArray[0]]) {
    bookObj[keyArray[0]] = bookObj[keyArray[0]] || [] 
    bookObj[keyArray[0]] = [...bookObj[keyArray[0]], data[obj]]
  } else {
    bookObj[keyArray[0]] = {}
    bookObj[keyArray[0]] = data[obj]
  }
  result[keyArray[1]] = bookObj
  return result
  
}, {})

const finalResult = Object.values(result).reduce((finalResult, obj) => {
  finalResult.push({book: obj})
  return finalResult
}, [])

console.log(finalResult)
```

> **Note**:
> In the final result you are expecting `borrowedBy` something like this, but the is not possible in an object. As the last value will override the previous one. So I created an array and pushing the names to that array.

```
...
"borrowedBy": {
               "name": "John Doe",
               "name": "John Doe Jr.",
           }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

split on "_" and fill in relevant properties in each book object.

```js
const rekey = key => key.split('_')

const res = []
for(const [k,v] of Object.entries(data)) {
  const [key, idx, path] = rekey(k)
  const {book} = res[idx] = res[idx] || { book: {} }
  if (path) {
    book[key] = book[key]||[]
    book[key][path] = v
  } else book[key] = v

  // if you will have nested array paths:
  /*let ptr = book
  path.unshift(key)
  while(path.length > 1) ptr = ptr[path[0]] = ptr[path.shift()]|| []
  ptr[path.pop()] = v*/

}
console.log(
  res
)
```

```html
<script>
data={
  "bookTitle_0": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
  "bookDescription_0": "Published in 1960, this timeless classic explores human behaviour and the collective conscience of The Deep South in the early 20th century. Humour entwines the delicate strands of prejudice, hatred, hypocrisy, love and innocence to create one of the best novels ever written.",
  "author_0": "Harper Lee",
  "borrowedBy_0_0": "John Doe",
  "borrowedBy_0_1": "John Doe Jr.",
  "bookTitle_1": "1984",
  "bookDescription_1": "Although 1984 has passed us by, George Orwell’s dystopian, totalitarian world of control, fear and lies has never been more relevant. Delve into the life of Winston Smith as he struggles with his developing human nature in a world where individuality, freewill and love are forbidden.",
  "author_1": "George Orwell",
  "borrowedBy_1_0": "John Doe III"
}
</script>
```